# Why wasn't Monica's cousin invited to her bridal shower?

Tags: plot-explanation, friends

From *Friends* S07E19, "The One With Ross and Monica's Cousin", it seemed that Monica got along with her cousin Cassie and I'm sure Rachel & Phoebe would know of her staying with Monica with the main characters being such close friends.

**Why then wasn't she invited to the bridal shower?** Would this be a plot hole because it's only until the end of the episode that Phoebe and Cassie are seen to share screen space possibly implying that Rachel & Phoebe never ran into her until after the shower.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You stumbled on the answer.

### They didn't know Cassie was in town.

Monica has been busy with work, the wedding, Cassie and Joey's *problem*, so she didn't tell them.

Rachel says she called everyone in Monica's phone book, but maybe Cassie wasn't on it (they have grown apart and are now reconnecting), or maybe Cassie doesn't have a cell phone (not uncommon for the 90's) and, since she is not at home, she didn't pick up her phone.